# Find the distribution of the vector $(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> A metal producer produces 3 types of metal sticks, Type 1, Type 2 and Type 3. It produces monthly, $20\%$ of type 1, $30\%$ of type 2, and $50\%$ of type 3. For a quality control, 40 sticks are chosen randomly. Let
>
> $$Y_i = \text{number of sticks type i}$$
>
> Find the distribution of the vector $(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$

So Im not being able to find this distribution. I know that it should be

$F_{Y_1Y_2Y_3}(y_1,y_2,y_3)=P(Y_1 \leq y_1, Y_2 \leq y_2, Y_3 \leq y_3)=P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{3}(Y_i \leq y_i)\right)$

But I am geting mixed up since the variables $Y_i$ don't look independent to me. Any hint?

Comment: I think the $Y_{i}$ are independent since $Y_{1} \cap Y_{2}$ does not make any sense. A stick can either be type $1$ or type  $2$ but not both.

Comment: The $Y_i$ are random variables, not events.

Comment: Ah, my bad. $Y_{1} + Y_{2} + Y_{3} = 40$ which makes them dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Not intended to be a complete solution.
$\newcommand{\P}[1]{\mathbb{P}\left(#1\right)}$

**Hint**: What is the distribution of the $Y_i$ for each $i$? Take $Y_1$ for example. Of your $40$ sticks, the probability that a single stick is of type $1$ is a *constant* $20\%$. Furthermore, there should be independence of stick types among each stick (i.e., the probability that a stick is of type $i$ should not affect the probability that a stick is of type $j$, $j$ possibly being equal to $i$).

**Hint**: So you have three types of these variables. What's a generalization of this type of variable?

Comment: What i was thinking is, if $Y_3 = 40$, for example, that will inmediately imply that $Y_2 = Y_1 = 0$, that doesn't make them dependent in some way?

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado Oh, I'm sorry. That's wrong. The random variables aren't independent (they are dependent, as you pointed out), but the stick types among each stick are indeed independent.

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado See my revised post.

Comment: The distribution is binomial, but Im not being able to "translate" to independent variables, knowing that the sticks are independent of one another

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado As you might guess, if $n_j$ is the number of sticks of type $j$, then you probably have some form of $(0.2)^{n_1}(0.3)^{n_2}(0.5)^{n_3}$, where $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = 40$, in your probability function. Consider the binomial case for example - look at $Y_1$. We have $(0.2)^{n_1} \cdot 0.8^{40-n_1}$ multiplied by the number of ways that you can choose $n_1$ things from $40$ things, i.e., $\binom{40}{n_1}$. What is the number of ways you can split $40$ things into $3$ groups of sizes of $n_1$, $n_2$, and $n_3$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $Y_i$ for any value $i$. Let us define a random variable $D_j$ where $D_j = 0$ if stick $j$ is not of type $i$. Otherwise, $D_j = 1$. Therefore,

$$Y_i = D_1 + D_2 +D_3 + .. + D_{40}$$

If $Y_i$ has value $n$, then we have $n$ sticks of type $1$ and $40-n$ sticks of type $2$. This is essentially a binomial distribution. For all 3 variables, it is a multinomial distribution.